# SP Services Does not Open Link Correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, spservices

I was looking at my code and it seems that `tempObj2.filename = $(this).attr("ows_URL")` grabs the URL and Description field which makes the a href invalid when opening in the front end. When a user click on the docuement it says https://google.com,https://google.com instead of https://google.com

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $().SPServices({
            webURL: url2,
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: listName2,
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Topic_x0020_Area'/><Value Type='DataType'>High Hazard</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'/></OrderBy></Query>",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='URL' /><FieldRef Name='Topic_x0020_Area' /></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                console.log("Status:" + Status)
                console.log(xData)
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    tempObj2 = {};

                    tempObj2.title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                    tempObj2.filename = $(this).attr("ows_URL");

                    $(tempObj2).each(function(i,el){
                        htmlOutput2 +="<span style='display:block'><img src='https://www.pngkit.com/png/detail/864-8648305_arrow-clipart-embellishment-small-arrow-icon-white-png.png'> <a href='"+this.filename+"'>"+this.title+"</a></span>";
              });
              if(htmlOutput2!=""){
                $("#trainingList").html(htmlOutput2);
              }
            });
          }
        });
   });
```

How do I hide the description field or just grab the URL directly?

Answer (score 1):

You could just split the `ows_URL` value and keep just the URL part of the value.